# Convert Uploaded File to POJO

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Is there a way to convert an uploaded file to a custom POJO, this class has a constructor that takes an `Inputstream` as an argument:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<String> upload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
    Image image = new Image(multiPartFile.getInputStream());
    ...
}
```

I want to avoid the manual construction of the Image object and received already constructed like:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<String> upload(@RequestParam("file") Image image) {
    ...
}
```

There are solutions like [this one](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-file-upload-example/) that apparently set a property of the object, but I can't set that property because I'm not in control of the `Image` object so the only way to set the `InputStream` is via constructor, [this post](http://www.greenpath.pl/2012/03/spring-framework-and-file-upload/) apparently use a converter to achieve exactly what I want, I have created such a converter and registered via `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.addFormatters` but it's never called, it looks like Spring creates an object using the default constructor and never calls the converter.

Comment: What do you exactly need to do with your object after parsing it from `MultipartFile`?

Comment: After I get the `image` object I send it to another service component for further processing and I read some properties of the Image like width and height.